# Sending request to API iteratively using requests in python

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I have made an API request as follow:

```
response = requests.get('{}/customers'.format(API_URL), headers=headers,  params = {"sort_by":'id', "min_id": 0})
data1 = response.json()
```

each request returns 1000 entries as a list, hence data1 is a list of 1000 elements. The total data I am trying to pull is 100,000 rows. Meaning I should play with the `min_id` to pull those. The way I was doing this was as follow:

step one is:

```
response = requests.get('{}/customers'.format(API_URL), headers=headers,  params = {"sort_by":'id', "min_id": 0})
data1 = response.json()
```

this gives:

```
[{'id': 6,
  'a': 'x',
  'b': 'y',
  'c': 'z'},...,
{'id': 9994,
  'a': 'm',
  'b': 'n',
  'c': 'o'}]
```

In the above output you can see the fist and the last element, so now I see that the last **id is 9994**, and now I make the second request as:

```
response = requests.get('{}/customers'.format(API_URL), headers=headers,  params = {"sort_by":'id', "min_id": 9995})
data2 = response.json()
```

where now the **min_id starts from 9995**. I can make 100s of this requests and extract the whole data, but this is not certainly efficient. I wonder if I can make an iterative function to do this. Such that on each iteration the min_id is being replaced by the `id` value of the last pull plus 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `max()` function to find maximum id and then update the parameter accordingly. Pseudocode:

```
min_id = 0
all_data = []
for r in range(100):
    print('Request no. {}..'.format(r))

    response = requests.get(
        "{}/customers".format(API_URL),
        headers=headers,
        params={"sort_by": "id", "min_id": min_id},  # <-- use min_id here
    )
    data1 = response.json()
    
    # find maximum id in data1 and update min_id
    min_id = max(data1, key=lambda k: k['id']) + 1

    # store data1 to all_data
    all_data.extend(data1)
```